# Deceleration parameter interval for LCDM model

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, data-analysis

In Plancks 2018 results, a value for the redshift at which the acceleration begun it is shown. Showing that this happen at redshift $ z=0.6 $. I was wondering if there is a confidence interval for this redshift as similar as we have for the EOS parameter which is $ w_{\text{de}}^{(0)}=-1.028\pm0.032 $ ?